# How to draw a dynamic drawing over a layout

Tags: android

I am trying to make a thermometer. For this I have an image of a thermometer(a png file) which i have inserted
into the layout using ImageView. Now I want to draw a line over this image to show the effect of temperature reading.

Here is my code.

main.xml

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ImageView 
</ImageView>
<com.focusone.Android.DrawExample.CustomDrawableView    
    android:id="@+id/custom_drawable_view"   
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    height='100'
    /> 
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

DrawExample.java

```
package com.focusone.Android.DrawExample;

public class DrawExample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

}
```

CustomDrawableView.java

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

    public CustomDrawableView(Context v,AttributeSet as){ 
        super(v,as); 
        drawShape(as); 
    } 
    public void drawShape(AttributeSet ast) {

        int x =45; int y=15 ; int width=5; int height=0 ;
                    height= Integer.parseInt(ast.getAttributeValue(null, "height"));   
                    mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());   
                    mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);   
                    mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height); 
    }
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Now I can draw a line on top of the thermometer image using this program.

But how do i change the height of line during runtime.
Since height=100 is written in the xml file I don't know how I can change it.

Please somebody help me.

Comment: By the way.. why didn't you just extend the ImageView class? Then you wouldn't have to care about drawing the image. You could focus on drawing your shape.

Comment: I would try a FrameLayout. First image then a custom view on top, as the AbsoluteLayout is deprecated. To place the thermometer anywhere on the screen one can insert this FrameLayout into a RelativeLayout by setting its top and left margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you don't need to pass attributes in drawShape(AttributeSet ast) but just height in your constructor CustomDrawableView(). Then as Chris said you should have another method in the custom view like

```
public void setTemperature(int tmp){
  drawShape(tmp);
  invalidate(); //this will call onDraw()
}
```

In your main activity make a reference to your custom view so you can call its public methods

```
  CustomDrawableView temperatureView = 
                  (CustomDrawableView) findViewById(R.id.custom_drawable_view);

  temperatureView.setTemperature(50);
```

Comment: why even make `setTemperature` static? In my opinion, this doesn't make sense. Sure, one could reason that you're only ever drawing one single temperature. But dare if you'd like to draw yet another temperature. The `instance` variable would become unnecessary, as well...

Comment: You are right, there is no need to comlicate with static methods here.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Make "height" a member of your `CustomDrawableView`
- Then create a method `setHeight(int height)` where you change the value of height.
- Then in your activity use `(CustomDrawableView)findViewById(R.id.custom_drawable_view)` to get a reference to your viewObject.
- Then change the value as you like with calling `setHeight(x)`

hope that helps